# Can't pay release version of my app: This version of the application is not configured for billing

Tags: android

I have an android app. I create a release version of my app (ver.1.0). I sign my APK with the release key. Nice. In my app, I have paid modules. When I try to pay my release app version I get an error:

```
This version of the application is not configured for billing
```

[image]

I have published my app (same version 1.0) to the Google Play. After Google's successfully published my app I downloaded it. And try to pay. and success gets a paid message.

[image]

The question is:
Why I can't pay in the release version?

Comment: You can't purchase item from release build unless you publish it to play store.If you want to test your subscription then add your email id to test user list and in licence testing, then you can test purchase flow.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology Send my email id to test user? What do you mean. Public my app BETA version in play store?

Comment: Test the application in release mode  or test in the app on closed testers.

Answer (score 10):

To Test subscription in release APK add your email id to test user list and in licence testing, then you can test purchase flow.

```
Add Email to test user:
Play console> select your app > Development tools > Internal app sharing > Manage testers> add your email 

Add Email to Licence Testing
Play console > Settings > Developer Account > Account Details > Licence Testing > add your email in Gmail accounts with testing access
```

Then upload your app to alpha and share test url.

Comment: Thank you. I've been waiting for 30 mins and I would not have resolve it without this.

Comment: Your solution is really helpful and saved my time man. Thank you :-)

Comment: I spent a decade to overcome this issue. I also checked to mark the testers list but unfortunately, it didn't work. There's another list called 'auto-generated license testers' I also needed to add my email to that list and checked and mark it. 

OMG! Thank You so much for the hint. You saved my ass big time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you removed com.android.vending.BILLING permission as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" tools:node="remove"/>
```

or you forgot to add this permission com.android.vending.BILLING

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Comment: For version 4.0 we don't need this permission. Could you confirm